# Shortcut directly to specific screen

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

There are some apps I that I only ever access for one specific purpose. I’d like to create a shortcut into a specific screen in the app - for example, open the app and navigate to charge history. Alternatively, I'd like to alias a series of actions to one action, so I can open it and navigate to the relevant part of the app quickly. Does anything like this exist? I've read about `QCustomShortcut`, not sure if it's a) suitable and b) safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Deep inks" into apps have to be supported by the app itself. Each app defines "activities" and you can only open the app if there is an activity for that screen you want and the activity has to be exported.

An app that allows you to list available activities and create shortcuts for them is [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher) just as an example.